# I need help in Resourceful routing and :id accessing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resources, rails-routing

How do i access the book id in like method from `like_book_path(@book),:method=>:post` .As you can see,this link is under the book loop.What do i need to do to make `like_book_path(@book)` carry  the book_id and how would i access it in like action?
so far in the view i can get the id through `book.id` .Any help will be greately appreciated.

View:

```
<% @books.each do |book|%>
  <%= book.name%>
  <%= link_to "like this book", like_book_path(@book), :method => :post %>
<%end%>
```

Book controller:

```
def like
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  #other methods to facilitate like functionality   
end
```

Route:

```
resources :book do
  member do
    post :like
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should replace your loop with:

```
<% @books.each do |book|%>
  <%=book.name%>
  <%=link_to "like this book",like_book_path(book),:method=>:post %>
<%end%>
```

the difference is just to use `book` instead of the non existing `@book`.

Comment: I am getting closer i think,but how do i access it in the controller `params[:id]`still cant find the id even though i can see it in the log ` Processing by BookController#like as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"5eWRqPg3ABKVR/HgTI2oVA8DEd1+hJUDVZktiFbhQr4=", "id"=>"11"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Book without an ID):`